# I have doubts about intercontract communication

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, inline-action

I have read that:

> In order to call an inline action, that is to call an action of contract A from contract B, there is a need to set some special permission. In this case, the Ram payer for the action in contract B must-have “accountname A@eosio.code” permission in its active. In a case, if account C needs to call an action in account A through a contract in account B, then account C need to set the accountB@eosio.code in its active.

But I observed that:

> 1. Contract B must-have “accountname B@eosio.code” permission in its active even to call function from contract A & not “accountname A@eosio.code” permission in its active.
> 2. If account C needs to call an action in account A through a contract in account B, then account C need to set the
>      accountB@eosio.code in its active. This is true but is there any
>      alternative that C can use contract B to call action from contract A
>      without changing its permissions. Because in dapp it is not feasible
>      for every user to do that.

I'm confused a bit about the all this. Can anyone please give me a clear guidance? Also, in accordance with the v2.0Latest version

Answer (score 0):

If a contract has an inline action, the permission for running that action must be `eosio.code` from that contract account.
Thats it.

Example:
`accounta` is a smart contract with an inline action to `accountb`. Therefore `accounta` will need the permission `accounta@eosio.code`, as the contract will need to execute the inline action.

Comment: And what about some account who wants use actions in contract of accounta (with an inline action to accountb) ?

Comment: It's still accounta that is calling that action on accountb